# Import Monthly Sales for any given contact

Tags: import, order

Hopefully someone can distill my options here. Goal is to for each contact (not account), import monthly sales figures. What's the ideal data model to pursue. I do not need item level details, just a figure to have sales for:

```
Jan 2016: $xxxx
Feb 2016: $xxxx
Mar 2016: $xxxx
```

.
.
.

and so on.

I have looked at orders and products, but the data models for those seem needlessly complex given my limited use case of being able to see sales trends for any given contact. The current approach is having custom fields for sales during the last 30, 60, 90, 180 days.....

Thank you,

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

@jrjames83

You are going to need some object that captures at a minimum

- `Reporting (Sales) Date` (type Date)
- `Amount`

but the next obvious thing to add is

- `Product`

so you can track sales by product by period (even if initially you use only a single default Product).

The above will allow you to easily create interesting reports/dashboards in Salesforce that compare sales per contact year over year, same month last year, same quarter last year etc.

Now, should you exploit the existing OOB SFDC objects?

- YES - if you are using multi-currency with dated exchange rates (use Opportunity / Opportunity Product or Order / Order Line Item)
- YES - if you want to track expected sales for future dates (use Opportunity)

Putting multiple periods of data into separate fields (rather than as separate object rows) leads only to reporting issues.

You can associate an `Opportunity` to a `Contact` via a custom lookup field, `Order` already has such lookup OOB.

If you use Opportunity Product or Order Line Item, you can point at a `Product2` and capture additional metadata about that sold product.

One thing I have learned over many years with SFDC, is that there is much leverage to be gained from exploiting the correct data model rather than being expedient.  For example, some appexchange packages expect you to use OOB models of data to get  the most value from those packages.

Comment: thanks @crop1645 - I hear you regarding using default objects in any system. So if I hear you correctly: use the products sObject, if I don't care about product level detail just create 1 generic product. Each month, create an order for that given product and associate with a contact via a look-up field?

Comment: that is a plausible approach. You can use Order.BillToContactId if that makes sense to your use case. And the list price can be 0.00 too

Comment: Thanks - what is the effect of the list price? I take it the order will be the parent of a generic product, which is the child of an order. Is the list price required to bridge the contact to the order via the BillToContactId?

Comment: list price is useful in doing reports comparing sales price vs list price (discounts offered) or in validation rules on max allowable discounts when quoting. For your use case, 0.00 is probably OK since you are just capturing orders